# Appcelerator - SystemAlert without vibration?

Tags: audio, titanium, appcelerator, media

We use the latest ("dev") Titanium SDK 6.1 which has this new function for sound effects, SystemAlert (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.SystemAlert)

The issue Im having, is that every time we use it, it vibrates (the phone). I cant find in the documentation how to turn the vibration off, or turn it down.

In the app, e.g when a message arrives, it's annoying if the vibrator goes off every time.

We're using the SystemAlert instead of "default Media" because it doesnt disrupt the current media session (If the user listens to music in the background).

Is there a workaround or anything to this? Can we use the default Media object somehow instead?

Oh BTW, this is for iOS (iPhone).